# How to connect to other app users?

Tags: ios, sdk, client-server

I have this idea for an app on iPhone where you need to be able to connect to other people that are using the app.

I was thinking that I would need a server where all app users are registered that are online and that a user is connected with another one via this server with connections. Is that the right way or are there other options, better options, where I don't need to hire a server?

I hope this is a clear question. So is client <-> server <-> client the right way to connect?

Comment: What you are looking for is called Game Center and you can find a tutorial on how to get started here http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/game-center-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-part-12

Comment: @sangony Actually, gamecenter it's not a pretty clever idea for handling these types of situation where real time connectivity is involved.

Comment: If Game Center is not the right fit for your app, then you will have to decide on going with your own custom server setup for connecting long distance players or bluetooth for connecting short range players. It all depends on what connectivity you need for your app.

Comment: @sangony Yup, he's looking forward to have all users "connected" to one of other, that involves some custom server scripted behavior , and to interact in custom ways between them .

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have lot's to learn about the topic. 
Most of iPhone applications are based on connectivity, hosts (users) connecting to servers to retrieve or send information.

There's many more in depth than just a server client connection, but luckily for non network-acknowledged programmers there's some APIs that will do all the work for you, such as PARSE amongst others, they'll handle all the SSL , data management, even push requests.

My best guess for you, start from the basics. Good luck

Comment: Well, I'm currently creating a server for a windows game so I know what I'm talking about. I was just wondering if there were any other options since I've never developed for iOS before.
An API would be good though. I guess it's going to be be a server/client model

Comment: I'm currently working on a server/client model for an iOs game (: , if you do decide to go with the server/client model there are tons of complementary APIs to achieve using sockets and encryption protocols more easily! Google it's our friend!

Comment: Well, it's not really for a game but yes, google is indeed our friend :) Thanks for the help. I'll just use a client/server model then.

Answer (score 1):

New in iOS 7, the Multipeer Connectivity framework can connect up to 8 nearby devices`*` running the same app. No external server required.

For anyone interested, I created [MCSessionP2P](https://github.com/shrtlist/MCSessionP2P.git), a demo app that illustrates the ad-hoc networking features of `MCSession`. The app advertises itself via Wi-Fi or Bluetooth and programmatically connects to available peers, establishing a peer-to-peer network.

`*` = current value of `kMCSessionMaximumNumberOfPeers`

Edit: Added "nearby" to first sentence for clarity.

Comment: Hi, this sounds great, although, what if the users aren't "nearby" as the framework states they should be?

Comment: @Dries You would most likely have to go with an external server in that case.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the information. This Multipeer Connectivity framework looks great though. Thanks for telling me about this.